# touch event remains on previous area after slide an imageview and touhcable event fires on FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

Can any one help me with this issues,
I m using FrameLayout in design,

I have three images A,B and C
I need design like - Image B should be behind A and onTouch image C the Image B slideDown from A's back side, and it should clickable.
I m done with translate animation and i used FrameLayout for overlays of images.

**The problem is,**

**1)** B image is clickable and even if its on Backside of A, it gets Clicked and run its onClick method even when it is not appearing. So it should not be Clicked when its on Background.

**2)** When i touch image C, the B image SlideDown from A's backside, but B's clickable area is not moving from top, it remains on previous area where B was originally placed before SlideDown.

i need to slideup and slidedown Image B from A's Backside when Image C gets clicked and its touchable area should also get moved.

```
TranslateAnimation t =new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,0,35);
t.setDuration(400);
t.setFillAfter(true);   
t.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
menuSlideBgId.startAnimation(t);
inFram.startAnimation(t);ImageView shareMenuId = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubbleMenu);
shareMenuId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bub", 5000).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used ObjectAnimator and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look [how-to-disable-button-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204017/how-to-disable-button-click) this example is for buttons but you can do the same for imageViews hope it helps you.

Comment: Enable and disable will solve 1st problem, not the 2nd, the Clickable area should also move as the image slide. Thanks for reply.

Comment: the 2nd problem is strange to understand do you mean that the image move but the touchable area of the image doesnt?

Comment: yes, the image gets move and its touchable area remains same even when it gets moved downward.

Comment: Is the first time that I heard it, post your code or something to help you